# What is Perl Tk::Methods and Tk::Submethods statements usage?

Tags: perl

I'm looking for information about `Tk::Methods` and `TK::Submethods` statements often found in Tk widget source files. I searched the web and stack overflow and didn't find any useful info.

I specifically looking into `Tk::Text` widget implementation.
e.g.,

`Tk::Methods (... 'insert'...)`

Doesn't that statement mean `insert` has to be a methods within `Tk::Text` widget?

I couldn't find any reference to an `insert` subroutine?

i did find `Insert` (notice the capital `I`), so does `Tk::Methods` manipulate the input string in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `use`. `Methods` is a subroutine declared in `Tk.pm`, many widgets just call it.

The purpose of the subroutine might be guessed from the usage, or from its source (UTSL):

```
sub Methods
{
 my ($package) = caller;
 no strict 'refs';
 foreach my $meth (@_)
  {
   my $name = $meth;
   *{$package."::$meth"} = sub { shift->WidgetMethod($name,@_) };
  }
}
```

It creates the given methods in the caller's namespace, i.e.

```
package MyWidget;
Tk::Methods('insert');
```

would create `insert` method in the `MyWidget` class that would be implemented as

```
shift->WidgetMethod('insert', @_)
```

Comment: So why declaring it if there is no use of it?

Comment: fixed the code snippet. and what is the usage of this subroutine?